# App Store Metadata Rejected, listed 9 items. How do I found out which ones are the problem?

Tags: metadata

Got Metadata Rejected from App Store. I have done a lot of research online. But still couldn't figure out exactly what needs to be done.
I did my best to make sure the wording is appropriate. Replied the message in resolution centre about what I have modified. (understood that binary is fine).
But 1 day later, Apple replied saying please make sure that your app does not violate any of the guidelines listed in our previous message.

Here is the items they are talking about.
It is just a math game I made to calculate 24 from 4 numbers. Very straight forward.

I asked in my reply about which one is the problem because there are a few items are obviously not related to my app.

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> This type of app has been identified as one that may violate one or
> more of the following App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, these
> types of apps often:
>
> 1.1.6 - Include false information, features, or misleading metadata.
>
> 2.3.0 - Undergo significant concept changes after approval
>
> 2.3.1 - Have hidden or undocumented features, including hidden "switches" that redirect to a gambling or lottery website
>
> 3.1.1 - Use payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase to unlock features or functionality in the app
>
> 3.2.1 - Do not come from the financial institution performing the loan services
>
> 4.3.0 - Are a duplicate of another app or are conspicuously similar to another app
>
> 5.2.1 - Were not submitted by the legal entity that owns and is responsible for offering any services provided by the app
>
> 5.2.3 - Facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media from third party sources without explicit authorization from those sources.
>
> 5.3.4 - Do not have the necessary licensing and permissions for all the locations where the app is used

Comment: Good news. It just got approved. But is this what Apple normally do: give you 10 reasons, and you need guess which one?

Comment: i Got this same problem what should i have to do?

Comment: @Paul What did you do before getting approved?

Comment: @Paul I got same problem. How did you solve your own?